# Chrome DevTools - wrong coverage json?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to extract only the used javascript from a JS file, using the Coverage Chrome DevTools option. I have exported the coverage json file, then I used a PHP script to extract with substr:

```
$target_js = 'js/input.js';
$json_string = 'coverage.json';
$output_filename = 'output.js';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$output_js = '';

foreach( $obj as $arr ) {
   if( strpos( $arr['url'], $target_js ) ) {
    
    foreach ($arr['ranges'] as $name => $value) {
        $length = $value['end'] - $value['start'];
        $output_js .= substr($arr['text'], $value['start'], $length);
    }
    
    break;
  }
}

echo $output_js;
file_put_contents($output_filename, $output_js);
```

Extracting from the JS file the code from "start" to "end" as mentioned in the exported json file, will result a broken js file.

Do you know if there is a bug in DevTools and the returned ranges are not correct? Or maybe other way to extract the JS?
Thank you

Comment: The range is returned in bytes, not chars. However, I also noticed that the exported json file, has incorrect ranges. If you copy paste from the dev tools and compare with the json ranges, the amount of bytes are different.

Comment: Apparently, they are not counting double quotes, so it looks like a bug.

Comment: I have reported it to google, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1123293